# Post content via JSON API: CURL works, PHP not?

Tags: nodes, 9

I've got those modules enabled:

- HAL
- HTTP Basic Authentication
- JSON:API
- REST UI
- RESTful Web Services
- Serialization

When I run this command, the content is created.

```sh
curl \
--user demo:9aqW72MUbFQR4EYh \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' \
--header 'Content-type: application/vnd.api+json' \
--request POST http://www.demo.drupal/jsonapi/node/article \
--data-binary @payload.json
```

Now I try to read via PHP, which works fine too.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

// Update to a user on your Drupal site that has permissions to create content
$user = 'demo';
$pass = '9aqW72MUbFQR4EYh';
$url = 'http://www.demo.drupal';

$content_client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => $url,
    'timeout'  => 20.0,
]);

$res = $content_client->request('GET', '/jsonapi/node/mail/71adf560-044c-49e0-9461-af593bad0746');

$body = $res->getBody();
$stringBody = (string) $body;
var_dump(json_decode($stringBody, true));
```

I can't post content. The code I am using returns a 401, 402, or 500 error.

```php
$headers = [
  'Content-type' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
  'Accept' => 'application/vnd.api+json'
];
$payload['data'] = [
  'type' => 'node--article',
  'attributes' => [
    "title" => "My custom title"
  ]
]; 

$guzzleResponse = $content_client->post('/jsonapi/node/article', [
  'json' => json_encode($payload),
  'headers' => $headers
]);

if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
  $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 401 error is because you're not sending the basic auth creds like you are with your curl request. You need to add an Authorization header to your Guzzle request:

`'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($user . ':' . $pass),`

The 500 error is likely due to a malformed payload that JSONAPI can't parse. The value of `json` should be an associative array, not a JSON encoded string. See the Guzzle docs on [uploading JSON data](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=json#uploading-data).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues. I still had to change some details in the JSON payload, but now it's actually working. :)